# Laravel orWhere or different Model

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do a query that filters on 2 columns on one table OR 2 columns on another. This is what I have so far:

```
// In my controller
return $registry = Registry::search($first_name, $last_name)->get();


// In my model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function scopeSearch($query, $first_name, $last_name)
{
    $search = $query->where('coregistrant_first_name', 'LIKE', "%$first_name%")
                 ->where('coregistrant_last_name', 'LIKE', "%$last_name%")
                 ->orWhere(function($query) use ($first_name, $last_name)
                 {
                    $query->$this->user()->where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%$first_name%");
                 });

   return $search;
}
```

I have tried a lot of different things and now I'm stuck on the `$query->$this->user()` line with this error:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$[]
```

Anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: `$query->$this` At first glace my best guess is this is your issue? Shouldn't it be `$query->this->user()`? As its currently written you are looking for a member variable with the name of whatever string value is stored in the global variable $this.

Comment: Now I have this error - Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$this

Comment: Are you using php 5.4 or greater?

Comment: `$query->$this->user()->where` remove `$this->` and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using query builder to do it.

Answer (score 0):

@Keith, In Laravel, you can not use relationship for selecting data dynamically.

AS far as i know, Laravel support the following rules to retrieve data using relationship:

1. `$registers = Registry::with('user')->get();`
2. `$registers = Registry::where('xyz', '1')->get();`

   // then you can load the relationship if you needed

   `$registers->load('user');`
3. In your model

   `public function user() 
     {
        return $this->belongsTo('User')->where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%xyz%");
     }`

**Then From your controller:**

```
 $registers = Registry::with('user')->get();
```

1. If you have one to many relationship,

Say you have `licenses` relationship

// You can specify an operator and a count:

`$registers = Registry::has('licenses', '>=', 3)->get();`

Reference: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations

Comment: Have you tried, `Registry::where('xyz', 1)->user()->where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%xyz%")->get()`?